Calculating age groups over time in Power BI
I would like to calculate the number of active employees in age groups over time. I have found a couple of solutions online, but they do not consider that an employee's age changes and falls to different age groups over time.
I am aiming for a result like this example:



AgeGroup
2024-01
2024-02
2024-03
2024-04




21-30
15
16
16
15


31-40
21
19
18
19


41-50
25
27
26
27


51-60
10
11
12
13



I have tables:
Employee, EmployeeStatus, AgeGroup, Calendar
Tables' description
Table Employee is a list of employees with their date of birth.
Columns: EmployeeID, DateOfBirth
Table EmployeeStatus is a list of changes of status with an effective date. The status is 0 (inactive) or 1 (active) and of course one employee can be active and inactive several times (e.g. rehired, parental leave..).
Columns: EmployeeID, Status, EffectiveDate
Table AgeGroup is a list of age bins I want to track with a minimum and maximum age in the group. Columns: AgeGroup, Minimum, Maximum
Table Calendar is just a calendar. Columns: Date, Month
Relationships are:
Employee[EmployeeID]-EmployeeStatus[EmployeeID] one to many
Calendar[Date]-EmployeeStatus[EffectiveDate] one to many
AgeGroup is not connected, as I do not know how to.
I have a measure HeadCount calculating the number of employees at a certain time (e.g. date, end of the month):
HeadCount = 
VAR LatestAvailableDate = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        VALUES('Employee'[EmployeeID]),
        "Date",
        CALCULATETABLE(
            LASTNONBLANK(Calendar[Date], CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(EmployeeStatus))),
            DATESBETWEEN (Calendar[Date], BLANK(), MAX(Calendar[Date]))))
VAR LatestAvailableDateLineage = 
    TREATAS(LatestAvailableDate,
        Employee[EmployeeID],
        'Calendar'[Date])
VAR Result = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(EmployeeStatus[Status]),
        LatestAvailableDateLineage)
RETURN
    IF(Result = 0, BLANK(), Result)

Then I have a measure calculating the age of an employee:
Age =
AVERAGEX(
    'Employee',
    INT(
        DIVIDE(
            DATEDIFF('Employee'[DateOfBirth], MAX('Calendar'[Date]), DAY),
            365.25
        )
    ) * [HeadCount]
)

Finally an age group is calculated from the age:
AgeGroup = 
    CALCULATE(
        SWITCH(TRUE(),
            [Age] <= 20, "Below"
            ,[Age] <= 30, "21-30"
            ,[Age] <= 40, "31-40"
            ,[Age] <= 50, "41-50"
            ,[Age] <= 60, "51-60"
            ,"Above"))

The measures above are working fine, I am just not able to group the results and show the count.
EDIT:
Sample data
Employee



EmployeeID
DateOfBirth




001
1983-02-01


002
1983-03-01


003
1993-04-01



EmployeeStatus



EmployeeID
Status
EffectiveDate




001
1
2023-12-01


001
0
2024-03-01


002
1
2024-01-01


003
1
2024-02-01



AgeGroup



AgeGroup
Minimum
Maximum




21-30
21
30


31-40
31
40


41-50
41
50


51-60
51
60



Result



AgeGroup
2024-01
2024-02
2024-03
2024-04




21-30
0
1
1
0


31-40
2
1
0
1


41-50
0
1
1
1




Can you share some data ?

Added data sample.

Can you clarify your model?

I don't know what you mean by clarifying the model. All I had was described in the question. However, I found a solution and posted it below.

Solution is this measure. The AgeGroup is not connected to any of the tables, which is surprising for me, that it works.
AgeCount = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Employee),
        FILTER(Employee, Employee[Age] <= MAX(AgeGroup[Maximum]) && Employee[Age] >= MIN(AgeGroup[Minimum])))

